# How to expose Kubernetes API internally in new namespace?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

Kubernetes by default adds a `kubernetes` service in the default namesapce. This allows access to the kubernetes API from any pod in that namespace.

For example, I can

```
TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
kubectl exec -it $SOME_POD -- bash
curl -v https://kubernetes/api/v1/ \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -k -v
```

And get something like:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 22:16:09 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "groupVersion": "v1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "bindings",
      "namespaced": true,
  ...
```

If I create a new namespace, there is no `kubernetes` service by default. I'm trying to create one by using the following resource service definition (basically copied from the default namespace):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    component: apiserver
    provider: kubernetes
  name: kubernetes
  resourceVersion: "12"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: ClusterIP
```

But this doesn't seem to work since there seems to be tied to any pod.

Basically, I want the same behavior as in the `default` namespace in a newly created namespace.

Current Version:

```
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "5",
  "gitVersion": "v1.5.7",
  "gitCommit": "8eb75a5810cba92ccad845ca360cf924f2385881",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2017-04-27T09:42:05Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.7.5",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `kubernetes` service from other namespaces by qualifying the hostname:

The hostnames `kubernetes.default.svc`, `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`, and the IP contained in `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` will all resolve to the kubernetes API service from any namespace.

Following your example, you could do this from any namespace:

```
TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
kubectl exec -it $SOME_POD -- bash
curl -v https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/ \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" 
  -k -v
```

Comment: Small problem though: These two addresses resolve to two different IPs: `/app # ping  kubernetes.default.svc
PING kubernetes.default.svc (10.3.240.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- kubernetes.default.svc ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/app # echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
10.3.248.39` Seems like they should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think service IP is same for all the name spaces. for the new namespace kubernetes service IP comes to POD as environment variable **KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST**.

you can access api like this.

```
TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
curl -k -v https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST/api/v1/   -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN
```

I tested this version 1.7.1 . I didn't have the older version of the cluster. you can test this and update the status.

Thanks
SR